# SWT JFace: How to implement a "leveled or expandable TableViewer"?

Tags: tree, swt, jface, tableviewer, treeviewer

I think this question is quite common.

Recently I have got a requirement that I need to make a leveled or expandable table-like view. If you need an example, you can refer to Mac OS X's Activity Monitor:
[image: Leveled rows in a table view]

At the same time I tried an example here which meets my requirement quite a little:
[image: SWT one]
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm

But it has some problems:
1. It's using SWT's `Tree` class not JFace classes;
2. I think it needs a repeat implementation of some JFace viewer classes's functions such as sorting by clicking a column header, filter and so on.

While I was feeling desperate, I found that Eclipse itself has a perfect view, its "Problems" view:
[image: Problems view in Eclipse]

So I think there must be a way to do it elegantly, for example extend JFace's `TableViewer` or `TreeViewer` class.

But I need help, since I've searched a lot in Google with no good result. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simply a [`TreeViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewer.html). Note that you can add [`TreeViewerColumn`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewerColumn.html)s to it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank you Alexey, it is really the truth.

Also I found a useful link here:
http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet026TreeViewerTabEditing.java?view=markup

Comment: "OK, thank you Alexey, it is really the truth." In this case you should accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in usage with EclipseRCP & ViewPart:

http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=swt-jface:treetableviewer